# ATP generation during respiration

Tags: botany, respiration

How many ATP molecules are generated from oxidation of FADH2 formed during complete oxidation of 10 molecules of maltose?

1. 40
2. 60
3. 80
4. 20

My method-

1. As maltose is a disaccharide ( made up of two glucose molecules )and for one glucose molecule , 2 FADH2 are formed after complete oxidation.
2. Then for one maltose molecule 4 FADH2 will be formed (since maltose has 2 glucose molecules).
3. Such 10 molecules of maltose will give 40-FADH2.
4. 1-FADH2 produces 2ATP during oxidative phosphorylation ,so total ATP formed =80

Comment: Try not to ask homework questions(direct option based questions) on this site. You'll get downvoted everytime. First, try to solve the question by yourself. If you encounter any problem in any step or can't understand something, then put forward your methods and ask the question(how should we do it and all). You can ask any conceptual problems related to particular topics but remember : NEVER post direct questions.

Comment: its not homework one it was asked in exam

Comment: look how i solved in  EXAM

Comment: as maltose is disaccharide made up of two glucose molecules and for one glucose molecule 2-FADH2are formed after complete oxidation then for one maltose molecules 4-FADH2 will be formed (2*2[2 in glucose{fadh2}]and [maltose=glucose+glucose])and such 10 molecules of maltose so40 FADH2(4*10).And each FADH2 produces 2ATP during oxidative phosphorylation so TOTAL ATP formed-80(40*2)

Comment: i know it's not a homework question (if u take the meaning literally). What I'm saying is try to make your question look much more presentable (like add your methods,thinking,reasoning,sources you use,etc.). If you don't show your efforts in finding out the answer, people will be less interested in answering it. And it'll also get downvoted since it'll seem like you didn't even take the effort to do it. You just posted it to get the answer. You're new to this site, so it'll take sometime to get used to it. So, don't worry if you're getting downvoted. just better luck next time!  =)

Comment: As far as i can see, you have done nothing wrong. Maybe the answer given is wrong?

Comment: @Bhavya-No problem =)